# Max RAM per slot - Asus motherboard

Tags: memory, motherboard

I'm looking to expand my virtual lab so I'll need more RAM. I have an [Asus M4A88TD-V EVO/USB3 motherboard](http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/M4A88TDV_EVOUSB3/specifications/). The specifications state:

> 4 x DIMM, Max. 16GB, DDR3 2000(O.C.)/1333/1066 Hz ECC, Non-ECC, Un-buffered Memory
>   Dual Channel Memory Architecture

I came across a few comments mentioning the fact that it needs 4 * 4 GB RAM modules because it won't be able to access all the memory in configuration 2 * 8 GB. A web based configurator throw up the same info. I would definitely prefer the 2 * 8 GB so I could eventually reuse it on my next configuration.

Comment: Check the manual.  It lists which configurations it supports.  Besides the speed of the memory is really slow.  Given how cheap it is I suggest just purchase the cheapest memory you can find and upgrade to 16GB.

Comment: Well now I'm confused. The official Asus support page [link] http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/socketAM3/M4A88TD-M/AMD_DDR3_4DIMM_model_list_report.pdf 
, mentiones 2*8 GB Adata sticks as compatible. Funny thing is that the list contains modules with unsupported frequency ( 2000+ MHz). So I doubt it refers directly to my board (why Asus, why?)

Comment: @ Ramhound: the paper manual, in the RAM compatibility list, doesn't mentione any 16GB RAM combination. The manual doesn't mention any limitations as per slot. But it's written all over the box it supports 16GB. Asus thanks for clarity. Still unsure..

Comment: If the Asus support page says that 2*8GB at a certain frequency was tested then it was tested.  There is no doubt in my mind pdf you linked to is for your board and only your board.

Answer (score 2):

Asus M4A88TD-V EVO/USB3 does not support 2*8GB RAM modules.
The paper manual, under Memory configurations, clearly states:
You may install 512MB, 1GB, 2GB and 4GB unbuffered ECC and non-ECC DDR3 DIMMs into the DIMM sockets. So the only possible configuration to bring the motherboard to a full 16 GB RAM configuration is to install 4*4 GB modules.

Answer (score 1):

The motherboard has a limited size of memory per slot;this is a 'hard limit' because of the bandwidth a memory controller or bus can support. If you were to use 2*8gb and it were to see the chips, it is extremely unlikely it would work or even boot up. Your best bet is to not purchase 16gb and stay with 8 to save money until your next build of you are concerned about it.

Comment: I finally got an answer from Asus, a very generic: "The MB suppports 16 GB max memory. To install 16GB you must use 4 dimms x 4 GB."
No other explanation provided, guess it would be a good idea to mention this limitation in the manual.